# Can Rubeloader be made to work with Intellij and latest libGDX which does not support JDK 1.6

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea, libgdx, box2d

I am just starting to look at simple 2D game development and I have I am looking at using Intellij with libGDX (for its box2d and multiple platform support), RUBE (box2d GUI editor) and RubeLoader (reads RUBE json files and creates box2d world). I have have tested libGDX and Intellij with the Java jdk 1.8 and have resolved some project setting to get that working. I next tried to add the RubeLoader to a base Intellij setup with libGDX and an error tells me there is no support for jdk 1.6 in the project. I removed jdk 1.6 since it is incompatible with the latest version of libGDX. My question is what do I modify to get RubeLoader to work with the later jdk. Do I clone it and manually repoint everything - will that work? Has anyone else encountered this issue.

Thanks

Comment: I think there is more than one RUBE loader that can be used with libGDX. It might help to link to the one you're asking about.

Comment: There are only two I know of and one has not been updated in a year. The other I assume is a fork of the first and it was last updated 3 months ago. Here is the link [RubeLoader](https://github.com/tescott/RubeLoader). If there are more please let me know.

Comment: The one that has not been updated in over a year is at this link [gdx-rube](https://github.com/cvayer/gdx-rube). I have not tried it but it looks like it cannot handle load images for RubePolygonSprite.

Comment: I should clarify, you are right there are a ton on RUBE loaders but ony two that I know of that work with Java. Sorry and is compatible with an Development IDE like IntelliJ.

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean when you say "this issue", and what "work" means. Does it compile? Does it compile but not run? Does it run but not load? Does it load but the result is incorrect?

Comment: Sorry I can't even get to the compile point. When I attempt to setup RubeLoader in Intellij with a libGDX base already imported I get an error saying that jdk 1.6 is not present. I assume this means it will not be able to read json files output from RUBE. I did not attempt to go further as it appears to not work. I also noticed that all of the libraries are pointing to Eclipse library's so at the very least I will have to repoint all of that before attempting agin. Perahps I am stopping too soon? I will attempt to import a RUBE exported json file and see what happens later this morning. Thanks

Comment: For the record... LibGDX is completely compatible with Java 6 (JDK 1.6). RoboVM projects do require Java 7 (JDK 1.7) to compile, however.

Comment: That's good to know. I thought all of libGDX required jdk 1.7. RoboVM is the new project you are working on for Apple iOS compatability, is that correct? Also I contacted the author of RubeLoader and he said he has a version running with JDK 1.7 but has not put it on GitHub yet.

Comment: late to the show but for others : You need to add the rube download into a libs directory under core and then add the src component to your sourcedirs in your build.gradle. e.g in core/build.gradle  sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/","libs/RubeLoader/RubeLoader/src" ]

Answer (score 0):

I used JDK 1.7 and it worked in Intellij